# One action button for multiple outputs shiny

Tags: r, shiny, action-button

I have shiny app which will give me 6 plot and if i want download the plot or data used to plot on csv. I wanted to a run button which will start the process of all six plots. Is it possible to do that? I checked about multiple outputs with a single action button. It was not very clear to me. I would also like to have clear action button which will clear all the inputs and outputs.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "IDF"),
                dashboardSidebar(
                                 sidebarMenu(
                                   menuItem("Data", tabName = "dataimport"), 
                                   menuItem("Stationary IDF", tabName = "Stidf"),
                                   menuItem("Non-stationary IDF", tabName = "NStidf"),
                                   menuItem("IDF under climate change", tabName = "Gcmidf"))),
                dashboardBody(
                  tabItems(
                    tabItem(tabName = "dataimport",
                            fileInput("file","Hourly precipitation data(.csv format)",accept = ".csv"),
                            checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                            radioButtons('UserCov',"Mention if there is a local covariate to be added, if Yes add the file", 
                                                                                      choices = list("No" = 1,"Yes" = 2), inline = T),
                            fileInput("cov","Local covariate data(.csv format)",accept = ".csv"),
                            checkboxInput("head", "Header", TRUE),
                            numericInput("lat","Latitude", value = c()),
                            numericInput("lon","Longitude", value = c()),
                            radioButtons('gcm', "Select the GCM", choices = list("MPI" = 1,"MRI" = 2,"CNRM"=3,"EC" =4,"MIR"=5), inline = T),
                            sliderInput("fut", label = h4("Select the starting point of time period"),min = 2015, max = 2100, value =  2020)),
                    tabItem(tabName = "Stidf",plotOutput('SIDF')), 
                    tabItem(tabName = "NStidf",plotOutput('NIDF')),
                    tabItem(tabName = "Gcmidf", 
                            tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                        tabPanel("s1",plotOutput('plot1')),
                                        tabPanel("s2",plotOutput('plot2')),
                                        tabPanel("s3",plotOutput('plot3')),
                                        tabPanel("s5", plotOutput('plot4'))))
                            )))


 
    
   server <- function(input, output,session) {
      output$SIDF <- renderPlot({
          req(plotSt())
          print(plotinput(plotSt()))
      })
      output$NIDF <- renderPlot({
        req(plotNSt())
        print(plotinput(plotNSt()))
      })
      
      output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        req(PCC1())
        print(plotinput(PCC1()))
      })
      output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
        req(PCC2())
        print(plotinput(PCC2()))
      })
      output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
        req(PCC3())
        print(plotinput(PCC3()))
      })
      output$plot4 <- renderPlot({
        req(PCC4())
        print(plotinput(PCC4()))
      })
    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is my plot function

```
plotinput <- function(P){
      PG <- as.matrix(P)
      A = PG[1,];  B = PG[2,]; C = PG[3,]
      Z = matrix(0,LDR,LRP)
      for (j in 1:LRP) {
        for (i in 1:LDR) {
          if (C[i] != 0) { 
            Z[i,j] = A[i] +((B[i]/C[i])*(((-log(1-(1/RP[j])))^-C[i])-1)) 
          } else { 
            Z[i,j] = A[i] +((B[i])*(-log(-log(1-(1/RP[j]))))) 
          }
        }
      }
  
 
  col_set <- rainbow(nrow(Z))
  matplot(Z,type = "o", lty = "solid", 
          lwd = 2, xlab = "Duration (hr)",ylab = "Intensity (mm/hr)", 
          col = col_set, cex.lab = 1.5, cex.axis=1.5, 
          cex.main=1.5, cex.sub=1.5, pch = 21, xaxt='n')
  
}
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes.  Simply add a dependence on your actionButton to each `render`er that you want to be updated when you click `Go`.  Similarly, you can use an `eventReactive` that depends on your `Clear` button to empty your (reactive) data on which the plots depend.  Without a reproducible example, it's difficult to provide more concrete advice: you have a typo in your code at line 34 and have nor provided any test data.

Comment: From data input to each plot, there are many functions, so I am finding it difficult to show a small sample of my code. Thank you for your comment. I will try to search now what you a suggested.

Comment: The input to "plotinput" function is a 3x7 matrix.